# Lua v.5.2 audio.playbg command not working

Tags: audio, lua

##### I want to add nice background music to my Lua project.

##### But I can’t figure out how to do it.

I tried like it this

```
true = audio.playbg(/Documents/source/sound/ActionMusic.Mp3,boolean,0.3,0.0)
```

I expected to have action background music (ActionMusic.mp3) that repeats when over with 30% volume and sound from both speakers

Comment: What software are you writing Lua script for?  Where can we find documentation on the `audio.playbg` function?  It is not a standard Lua function.

Comment: The code you gave is not valid Lua code: true cannot be at the LHS of an assignment and you need to quote the path.

Comment: I tried to use the _audio library_ on the touchlua+ app. Also is it possible to play music with no librarys installed?